# Problem with SHAP plots for textual data that has been vectorized using tfidf

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, tf-idf, shap

For this line of code `shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_val_vec, feature_names=feature_names)`, my plot is coming out looking like this.
[shap summary plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCzjO.png)

I am unsure what to change to make it come out correctly.

X_val_vec is testing textual data that has been vectorized using tfidf. feature_names is equal to 'vectorizer.get_features_names_out()' Using a random forest model. This is my code for making the explainer object - 'explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X_train_vec, feature_names=feature_names, check_additivity = False, algorithm = "tree")' X_train_vec is text data used for training that is vectorized using tfidf.

I have been able to get the waterfall plot to work, but the summary plot and a few others are not coming out right.